Excel VBA Loop By Column from E to CS
Please help, I Want to Text to Column my data from E3 to till CS Column. Please help me with
LOOP.
Below is my code.
Sub TextToColumn()

Range("E3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Need to add Loop function till CS Column to convert value of the data.


Loop through each columns in UsedRange

Sub TextToColumn()
    Dim rngCol As Range
    For Each rngCol In Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("E:CS")).Columns
        With rngCol
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End With
    Next
End Sub


If you just want to remove double quote, below code is simpler.

Sub RemoveDoubleQuote()
    Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("E:CS")).Replace _
        What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub

